# deleting rows in bill of materials

Tags: vba, solidworks

I am currently trying to make macro which could filter my BOM (bill of materials) table, but it keeps getting error messages.

The goal is to delete all rows which contains text "No" in 9 column, could anyone help me with this?

```
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc

Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr

Dim swView As SldWorks.View

Dim swBomTable As SldWorks.BomTableAnnotation

Dim i As Integer

Dim swTableAnn As SldWorks.TableAnnotation

Dim nNumRow As Variant

Sub main()

 Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

 Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

 Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager

 Set swBomTable = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject5(1)

 Set swTableAnn = swBomTable



For i = swTableAnn.RowCount - 1 To 0 Step -1

nNumRow = swBomTable.GetIdForRowNumber(i)


 If nNumRow(i, 9) = "No" Then

swBomTable.Deleterow (nNumRow), True

End If

 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: did u try swBomTable.Deleterow nNumRow, True

Comment: look at this to see how to properly [process through a BOM table](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/English/api/sldworksapi/Get_Components_in_Each_BOM_Table_Row_VB.htm).  I can write up some code later if you do not figure it out from this link

Answer (score 1):

bevare this deletes all "no" rows.. like Nothing nowhere No NO no if you would like to look for no that stands alone then add spaces into the code on each side of "no" -> " no "

```
Option Compare Text
Sub deleter()
Dim xrow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(65000, 9).End(xlUp).Row + 1
xrow = 1

Do
    If Not InStr(1, Cells(xrow, 9).Value, "No") = 0 Then
        Cells(xrow, 9).EntireRow.delete
    Else
        xrow = xrow + 1
    End If
Loop Until xrow = lastrow
End Sub
```

If you need to look for No just with capital letter then remove option Compare Text dombine at your will
Hope I helped

Comment: If you are looking for more solidworks related answer then say a word and I can adjust the code

Answer (score 0):

This is code that I have used that might be helpful.  It will work if there is an assembly level BOM.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swFeat As SldWorks.Feature
    Dim swSubFeat As SldWorks.Feature
    Dim swBomFeat As SldWorks.BomFeature


    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swFeat = swModel.FirstFeature

    Do While Not swFeat Is Nothing
        If swFeat.GetTypeName2() = "TableFolder" Then
            Set swSubFeat = swFeat.GetFirstSubFeature
            Do While Not swSubFeat Is Nothing
                If swSubFeat.GetTypeName2() = "BomFeat" Then
                    Set swBomFeat = swSubFeat.GetSpecificFeature2()
                    Call ProcessBomFeature(swBomFeat)
                End If
                Set swSubFeat = swSubFeat.GetNextFeature()
            Loop
        End If
        Set swFeat = swFeat.GetNextFeature
    Loop
End Sub

Sub ProcessBomFeature(swBomFeat As SldWorks.BomFeature)

    Dim vTableArr As Variant
    Dim vTable As Variant
    Dim swTable As SldWorks.TableAnnotation

    vTableArr = swBomFeat.GetTableAnnotations()

    For Each vTable In vTableArr
        Set swTable = vTable
        Call ProcessTableAnn(swTable, swBomFeat.Configuration)
    Next vTable

End Sub

Sub ProcessTableAnn(swTableAnn As SldWorks.TableAnnotation, ConfigName As String)

    Dim nNumRow As Long
    Dim J As Long

    nNumRow = swTableAnn.RowCount
    Dim swBOMTableAnn As BomTableAnnotation
    Set swBOMTableAnn = swTableAnn

    For J = 0 To nNumRow - 1
        Dim bomCellText As String
        bomCellText = swTableAnn.DisplayedText(J, 9)
        If bomCellText = "No" Then
            swTableAnn.DeleteRow (J)
        End If
    Next J
End Sub
```